# How to access route after certain controller call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two routes

```
Route::post('checkout','CartController@billingSave');
Route::get('success','CartController@billingSave');
```

So after completing the billingSave method it will redirect to success page..
But if put /success also in url it shows the success page also..though he didn't complete the payment..is there anyway i could let access only the `success` url after completing the billingSave functionality?

means he can't access success url instead of completing the billingSave method ..or like don't give him access the `success` url?

Answer (score 3):

You could block the success route using laravel's Middleware https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware You can write your own middleware to check whether billingSave was done.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following route:

```
Route::get('success','CartController@billingSave');
```

to

```
Route::post('success','CartController@billingSave');
```

so that user cannot access it directly by using the `success` route in browser, **don't forget to show error page here**. It can only be accessed by form post method. After data saved successfully submit the form to `success` route.